# How to remove whitespace in inline styles?

Tags: php, regex, html-email

I have a php script which generates a html email. In order to optimise the size to not fall foul of Google's 102kB limit I'm trying to squeeze as unnecessary  characters out of the code as possible.

I currently use [Emogrifier](https://github.com/MyIntervals/emogrifier) to inline the css and then [TinyMinify](https://github.com/jenstornell/tiny-html-minifier) to minify.

The output from this still has spaces between properties and values in the inlined styles (eg `style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 16px"`)

I've developed the following regex to remove the extra whitespace, but it also affects the actual content too (eg this & that becomes this &that)

`$out = preg_replace("/(;|:)\s([a-zA-Z0-9#])/", "$1$2", $newsletter);`

How can I modify this regex to be limited to inlines styles, or is there a better approach?

Comment: How about using shorter CSS right away? Like `#fff` or `red` instead?

Comment: @AmigoJack My understanding is that shortened colour codes or names aren't reliable in email and so the full hex value should be used.

Comment: Please link to examples of unreliable cases, as CSS allows them [since 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS1-20080411/#color-units) - in doubt dump the whole idea of HTML e-mails.

Comment: Haven't actually tested, but "Using 3-digit, or shorthand, HEX codes is not a great idea. When 3-digit HEX codes are used in <table> and <td> tags, blue (or sometimes black!) backgrounds result, with no regard to the color specified" https://litmus.com/blog/background-colors-html-email

Comment: HTML element attributes are not CSS, that's the simple point - `<element attr="value">` is nowhere near CSS, not even if it coincidentially looks like it; only `style=""` is CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no bullitproof ways to not match the payload (`style=""` can appear anywhere) and to not match actual CSS values (as in `content: 'a: b'`). Furthermore consider also

- shortening the values: `red` is shorter than `#f00`, which is shorter than `#ff0000`
- remove leading and trailing bogus, like whitespaces and semicolons
- redesigning your HTML: i.e. using `<ins>` and `<strong>` can be effectively shorter than using inline CSS

One approach would be to match all inline style HTML attributes first and then operate on their content only, but you have to test for yourself how good this works:

```
$out= preg_replace_callback
( '/( style=")([^"]*)("[ >])/'  // Find all appropriate HTML attributes
, function( $aMatch ) {  // Per match
    // Kill any amount of any kind of spaces after colon or semicolon only
    $sInner= preg_replace
    ( '/([;:])\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9#])/'  // Escaping backslash in PHP string context
    , '$1$2'
    , $aMatch[2]  // Second sub match
    );

    // Kill any amount of leading and trailing semicolons and/or spaces
    $sInner= preg_replace
    ( array( '/^\\s*;*\\s*/', '/\\s*;*\\s*$/' )
    , ''
    , $sInner
    );

    return $aMatch[1]. $sInner. $aMatch[3];  // New HTML attribute
  }
, $newsletter
);
```

Comment: Here's a demo to express why direct regex manipulation is not reliable: https://3v4l.org/vohQS

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided sample input for us to use, but you have mentioned that you are dealing with html.  This should sound alarm bells that using regex as a direct solution is ill-advised.  When intending to process valid html, you should be using a dom parser to isolate the style attributes.

Why shouldn't you use regex to isolate the inline style declarations? **Simply put: Regex is "dom-unaware".**  It doesn't know when it is inside or outside of a tag (I'll provide a contrived monkeywrench in my demo to express this vulnerability.  Furthermore, using a dom parser will add the benefit of correctly handling different types of quoting.  While regex can be written to match/acknowledge balanced quoting, it adds considerable bloat (when executed well) and damages the readability and maintainability of your script.

In my demo, I'll show how spaces after colons, semicolons, and commas can be simply/accurately purged after isolating true inline style declarations.  I've gone that little bit farther (since color hexcode condensing was mentioned on this page) to show how regex can be used to reduce *some* six character hexcodes to three characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZUrne))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div style='font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif; background-color: #ffffff; '>
  <p>Some text 
    <span class="ohyeah" style="font-weight: bold; color: #ff6633 !important; border: solid 1px grey;">
      Monkeywrench: style="padding: 3px;"
    </span>
    &
    <strong style="text-decoration: underline; ">Underlined</strong>
  </p>
  <h1 style="margin: 1px 2px 3px 4px;">Heading</h1>
  <span style="background-image:     url('images/not_a_hexcode_ffffff.png');    ">Text</span>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node) {
    $style = $node->getAttribute('style');
    if ($style) {
        $patterns = ['~[:;,]\K\s+~', '~#\K([\da-f])\1([\da-f])\2([\da-f])\3~i'];
        $replaces = ['', '\1\2\3'];
        $node->setAttribute('style', preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $style));
    }
}
$html = $dom->saveHtml();
echo $html;
```

Output:

```
<div style='font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,serif;background-color:#fff;'>
  <p>Some text 
    <span class="ohyeah" style="font-weight:bold;color:#f63 !important;border:solid 1px grey;">
      Monkeywrench: style="padding: 3px;"
    </span>
    &amp;
    <strong style="text-decoration:underline;">Underlined</strong>
  </p>
  <h1 style="margin:1px 2px 3px 4px;">Heading</h1>
  <span style="background-image:url('images/not_a_hexcode_ffffff.png');">Text</span>
</div>
```

The above snippet uses `\K` in the patterns to avoid the use of lookaround and excess capture groups.

I am not writing a pattern that removes the space before `!important` because I have read some (not so recent) posts that some browsers express buggy behavior without the space.

Comment: @Amigo how close am I to solving this one for you?